# Woocommerce admin_notices does not work when woocommerce_order_status_changed hook fires

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-admin

I'm new to WordPress development and I'm currently encountering a dead-end.

I want an admin notice to be displayed in a WooCommerce order after the order's status has been changed.

With the following code, the notice doesn't appear:

```php
<?php

class TestNotice {
    public function testTheNotice() {
        add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', [$this, 'test'], 10, 4);
    }

    public function test(int $id, string $statusFrom, string $statusTo, WC_Order $order)
    {
        add_action('admin_notices', [$this, 'notice']);
    }

    public function notice()
    {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
            <p>This notice appears on the order page.</p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

}

$testNotice = new TestNotice();
$testNotice->testTheNotice();
```

I have tried setting the "priority" parameter of the "admin_notices" action to `20`, without success (I think it would have been useful if the nested action was the same as the one first called).

However, when I call "admin_notices" action directly in `testTheNotice()` method (and thus not calling "woocommerce_order_status_changed" action), it works (on every admin page, which is not what I want).

I thought it was because the `notice()` was somehow not recognised, but it actually is: the code below displays "This notice appears on the order page." on a blank page (which is not what I want and only for test purpose).

```php
<?php

class TestNotice {
    public function testTheNotice() {
        add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', [$this, 'test'], 10, 4);
    }

    public function test(int $id, string $statusFrom, string $statusTo, WC_Order $order)
    {
        call_user_func([$this, 'notice']); die();
    }

    public function notice()
    {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible">
            <p>This notice appears on the order page.</p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

}

$testNotice = new TestNotice();
$testNotice->testTheNotice();
```

I'm aware there's a special class and method for WooCommerce admin notices, and writing below code in `notice()` displays a notice, but with a purple border (because of the "update" css class, which I haven't found how to change) instead of a red border (which would be possible thanks to the "error" css class, which I don't know how to apply).

```php
$adminNotice = new WC_Admin_Notices();
$adminNotice->add_custom_notice("Test",'<p>This notice appears on the order page.</p>');
$adminNotice->output_custom_notices();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. It got me curious and made me dig into this `WC_Admin_Notices` class. And here's what I found out!

Well, before I talk about `WC_Admin_Notices` class, first let's talk about your first question!

> *"the notice doesn't appear"*

Because when the `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook fires there is no screen associated with it and it's not just notices, for example if you try to do a `print_r` and/or an `echo` they won't show anything either because there is no screen associated with that hook. The only way you could find out that you hit that hook is by using `die` function. In order to test this, you could do this:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'test', 99, 4);

function test($order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order_object)
{
  die('You hit the right hook!');
}
```

But if you replace the `die('You hit the right hook!')` function with `echo` or `print_r`, they won't show anything no matter how high you set the priority of the hook.

---

It gets interesting when you use `WC_Admin_Notices` class. If there is no screen associated with the `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook, then how does this class work? Well, here's how:

> [`class-wc-admin-notices.php`<sup>Class</sup>](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-notices.php)

1. It has a property called `$notices` which is a simple empty array.
2. When you call `add_custom_notice` method, it'll store the values you gave it, into the database and into the "options" table. The key would be "woocommerce_admin_notice_{the name you gave for example test}", and the value would be the message/notice you defined. **That's all it does! It stores your message/notice into the database.**
3. When you call `output_custom_notices` method, it'll check the `$notices` array, and check the database for any key value pairs stored in the options table with the format I just mentioned in number 2! Then, it uses a template called `html-notice-custom.php` in the following path:

> yourwebsite.com > wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > includes > admin > views > html-notice-custom.php
> [`html-notice-custom.php`<sup>Template</sup>](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/views/html-notice-custom.php)

The `html-notice-custom.php` file is responsible for outputting the html markup for custom notices and it'll give them a class called `updated` which will trigger a css rule that has a light purple color.

---

###### So the overall workflow of the `WC_Admin_Notices` class is:

- Stores your custom message into either an array or in the database
- Retrieves the stored key and value pairs when the screen loads!

Technically, that's all it does, well, in the simplest terms!

---

Since we don't want that custom light purple template, we could use the workflow that `WC_Admin_Notices` uses and write our own solution without using `WC_Admin_Notices` class.

We could use one of the following approaches:

- Use the combination of `$_SESSION` + `admin_notices` hook
- Use the combination of `cookie` or `local storage` + `admin_notices` hook
- Use the combination of `database` + `admin_notices` hook

---

I think, if we use `$_SESSION` + `admin_notices` hook approach, it'd be both safe and fast without even query the database for a simple string of text. Here's the solution I can think of at this moment:

Code goes into the `functions.php` file of your active theme.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'test', 99, 4);

function test($order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order_object)
{

  if ( $order_object && ($old_status != $new_status) ) 
  {

    $notice = 'This notice appears on the order page.';

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['your_custom_message_name'] = $notice;

  }
}

add_action('admin_notices', 'your_them_displaying_custom_admin_notice');

function your_them_displaying_custom_admin_notice()
{
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['your_custom_message_name'])) {

?>
    <div class='notice notice-error is-dismissible'>
      <p><?php echo $_SESSION['your_custom_message_name'] ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
    unset($_SESSION['your_custom_message_name']);
  }
}
```

**Note:**

- This works only if there is an order AND the `$old_status` is not equal to the `$new_status`.
- In the `$notice` variable, I put raw text, not html, since we put a `p` tag in the html section/template of the `admin_notices` hook.
- I've used `notice-error` class for the `div` tag which shows the `red color` for the notice. You could replace it with `notice-warning`, or `notice-info` or `notice-success`.

---

This answers has been fully tested on woocommerce `5.7` and works fine.