# Woocommerce order starus hook not triggering

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I´m trying to execute a function on order status change from Woocommerce order.

I´ve added the code bellow to my function.php file. To verify if the hook was triggered, I set a message on a global variable ($woo_status_msg) that is verified on the admin panel('all_admin_notices' hook). I´ve tried diferent hooks, like _processing, but nothing happens. [The message on the panel is updated, but whithout the woocommerce hook msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKOp4.png).

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'woocommerce_trigger_msg', 1, 0);
function woocommerce_trigger_msg()
{
    global $woo_status_msg;
    $woo_status_msg = 'OK, i´m here!'; 
}

add_action('all_admin_notices', 'print_msg_on_admin_panel');
function print_msg_on_admin_panel()
{
    printf( '<div class="notice updated"><p>Message: %s </p></div>', $woo_status_msg );
}
```

Comment: `echo`, `print_r` etc. won't work on `order status hook`. `die` would work however. If you want to read more about it and why that happens, you could read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69857967/woocommerce-admin-notices-does-not-work-when-woocommerce-order-status-changed-ho/ . And first two paragraphs of my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69864962/15040627. Try this `die('You hit the right hook!')`

Comment: Well, die function made what I needed: only verify the trigger of the hook... You really helped me! Thanks! But I didnt understand why the global variable wasn´´t carrying the content seted on the function called by the order status hook... I wondered that global variables would have the content all the time...

Comment: @DanielWeber Or enable debug logging in WP and log with error_log( 'Test' ); for example

Comment: oh, good... i'll try it next time... thanks!